# Match lines between pattern in a file and check for a word in those matched lines, if not found add the word

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

I have a big file with contents like below:

--- fruits_file.txt---

```
fruit:

apple 
orange

fruit:

grapes
mango

fruit:

banana
cherries
```

--> Requirement is to have apple in each of the fruit container like below

--- fruits_file.txt---

```
fruit:

apple

orange

fruit:

grapes

mango

apple

fruit:

banana

cherries

apple
```

Tried different ways, is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems you asked a [XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/) and then decide to edit your question to ask the real one. Please do not edit an already answered question to ask a new one. Instead, use [Ask question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) to post the new question. I hope people  who downvoted you retract their votes.

Answer (score 4):

You can process the file in the following way:

**0.** Let's assume your file looks as this:

```bsh
cat fruits_file.txt
```

```bsh
fruit:

apple
orange

fruit:

grapes
mango

fruit:

banana
cherries
```

**1.** Transpose the content of the file into a single line:

```bsh
paste -s -d ' ' fruits_file.txt
```

```bsh
fruit:  apple  orange  fruit:  grapes mango  fruit:  banana cherries
```

**2.** Pipe the output of the above command to `sed` and place new line before the string `fruit:`, pipe the output `|`, and use `sed` gain in order to remove the empty lines:

```bsh
paste -s -d ' ' fruits_file.txt | sed 's/fruit:/\nfruit:/g' | sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

```bsh
fruit:  apple  orange
fruit:  grapes mango
fruit:  banana cherries
```

**3.** Pipe the output of the above command to `awk` in order to append `apple` at the lines where it is missing:

```bsh
paste -s -d ' ' fruits_file.txt | sed 's/fruit:/\nfruit:/g' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | \
                      awk '{if (!/apple/) {printf "%s apple\n", $0;} else print}'
```

```bsh
fruit:  apple  orange
fruit:  grapes mango
fruit:  banana cherries
```

**4.** Pipe the output of the above command to `sed` in order to replace (expression 1) the multiple spaces by a single space and (expressions 2) append double whitespace at the end of each line:

```bsh
paste -s -d ' ' fruits_file.txt | sed 's/fruit:/\nfruit:/g' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | \
                      awk '{if (!/apple/) {printf "%s apple\n", $0;} else print}' | \
                      sed -r -e 's/\s{1,9}/ /g' -e 's/\s*$/  /'
```

```bsh
fruit: apple orange
fruit: grapes mango apple
fruit: banana cherries apple
```

**5.** Pipe the output of the above command to `sed` again in order to (expression 1) replace each white space by a newline character and (expression 2) add newline before each `fruit:` string. Then pipe the output to `head` in order to remove the last two empty lines:

```bsh
paste -s -d ' ' fruits_file.txt | sed 's/fruit:/\nfruit:/g' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | \
                      awk '{if (!/apple/) {printf "%s apple\n", $0;} else print}' | \
                      sed -r -e 's/\s{1,9}/ /g' -e 's/\s*$/  /'  | \
                      sed -e 's/\s/\n/g' -e 's/fruit:/fruit:\n/' | head -n -2
```

```bsh
fruit:

apple
orange


fruit:

grapes
mango
apple


fruit:

banana
cherries
apple
```

**6.** Redirect the output of the above command and create a new file:

```bsh
paste -s -d ' ' fruits_file.txt | sed 's/fruit:/\nfruit:/g' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | \
                      awk '{if (!/apple/) {printf "%s apple\n", $0;} else print}' | \
                      sed -r -e 's/\s{1,9}/ /g' -e 's/\s*$/  /'  | \
                      sed -e 's/\s/\n/g' -e 's/fruit:/fruit:\n/' | head -n -2 \
                      > fruits_new.txt
```

```bsh
cat fruits_new.txt
```

```bsh
fruit:

apple
orange


fruit:

grapes
mango
apple


fruit:

banana
cherries
apple
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

If you would like to keep the location of the word if it exists already otherwise append it to the end of the container, then try to use the following:

```
sed '/^$/d' fruits_file.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/fruit:/\nfruit:/g' | sed '/apple\|^$/! s/$/apple/' | tr ' ' '\n'> final_fruits.txt
```

**Old answer**

Use the following if the location of `apple` is not important.

```
sed -i.bak '/^$/d;/apple/d;s/fruit:/\nfruit:\napple/g' fruits_file.txt
```

`-i.bak`: is used to make a backup file. In this case: `fruits_file.txt.bak`

`'/^$/d'` : will remove blank lines (This is optional).

`'/apple/d'`: remove any line that contains `apple`.

`s/fruit:/\nfruit:\napple/g`: Add `apple` in a new line after `fruit:`.

Comment: As informed it is a big file and apple is in different locations in the fruit containers, like sometimes in the top and some time in bottom. i dont want to change the location of the existing apple , only i need to add new apple if it is not there... so above solution not working... but thanks for your support

Comment: @user261334: I've updated the answer.

Comment: It won't work, because it adds another apple , if apple already there.

Comment: @user261334: No, it works as expected, you can show me your example. Have you tried to run that on your file???

Comment: thanks for support, but i am afraid that is not working

Comment: sed 's/fruits:/\nfruits:\napple/g' t.txt

Comment: @user261334: Please read carefully, that's the old answer, See the **Update**

Comment: :
this
is
from
germany,
netherlands,
france
apple:
ripe
fruit

Comment: @user261334: You have changed the question completely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111400/discussion-between-user261334-and-navaro).

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a big file, we shall process each container individually and not load the entire file in memory. We can easily do it in Python3. Save it in `process.py` and the data in `fruits_file.txt`

```py
import sys

# This function checks if "apple" not in container then append it.
def add_apple_and_print(container):
    if container is not None:
        if "apple" not in container:
            container.append('apple')

        print("\nfruit:\n")
        print("\n\n".join(container))

# Open the file for reading
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:

     container = None                     # Initialize the container with None
     for line in f:                       # Read line by line
        line = line.strip()               # Remove trailing spaces
        if len(line) > 0:
            if line == "fruit:":
                add_apple_and_print(container)  # Print privious container
                container = []                  # Create a new container for current fruit section
            else:
                container.append(line)          # Add fruits to container

     add_apple_and_print(container)             # Print last container
```

then

```bsh
python3 process.py fruits_file.txt > fruits_file_with_apple.txt
```

Comment: Here we are manually adding fruit and appending it to container ,   forgot to say that sometimes i have fruit : "these are from germany" , and sometimes fruit : "These are from france", as this was big file forgot to mention about it... so this was little closer but not working .

Comment: Could you please confirm that all these header lines contain ```fruit:```.

Comment: Or any other pattern that exists in these lines.

Comment: - fruits : this is from germany, netherlands, france
  
  apple: ripe fruit
  orange: c vitamin
  banana: d vitamin

- fruits : this is from poland, austria
  
  orange: c vitamin 
  pineapple: a vitamin
  grapes: b vitamin
 
- fruits : this is from poland, austria
  
  pear: c vitamin 
  apple:  ripe fruit, vitamin a, b ,c
  pappya: a vitamin
 
- fruits : this is from sweeden, norway
  
  orange: c vitamin 
  pineapple: a vitamin
  grapes: b vitamin

Comment: i dont want to change the location of apple, only need to add in fruit container if apple is not there.

Comment: i updated exact file on the question, for clear reference.,

Comment: Updated: please use python3.7 or later.

Comment: It is better that you write a new question and tag me in the comment, I will put the the updated answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to find some commands to achieve that...
But I think that it would be easier to do such things with the help of some functional text editors. I recommend to use Visual Studio Code. You can use tool like `Find and Replace`. You can find every `fruit:` and replace it with:

```
fruit:

apple
```

But if it already has some apple, than in these 'fruit-containers' you can got some duplicates.

Comment: I mean, the vim approach is essentially the same as the top sed answer: `:g/apple/d` and `:%s/fruit:/&\rapple\r/`

Comment: All of the answers are modifying my apple location, in big file apple is present in different places,  and i dont want touch the existing location. my requirement is to check in the container if apple is there , else add apple in the container.   Yeah i am currently doing it with visual studio, but its a big file and tedious....